# Installating software off Ubuntu Store "frozen". How do I safely stop this/restart my system?

Tags: software-center

Okay, so today I wanted to try and install VirtualBox just to try it out. However, at some point I decided that I wanted to cancel it and found that the cancel button was greyed out. To add insult to injury, it appears that the application has already been installed onto my laptop despite what the Software Center says. Like... I can open and work with the software if I wanted to, even though you shouldn't be able to do that while the program is still installing.

I've heard from a friend of mine that if I restarted my computer while software is still being installed that I'd be risking a "general failure", but that I shouldn't worry because there's only a small chance of it happening. I honestly don't know what to do from here, because the cancel button for VirtualBox is greyed out and I have no idea what it's doing. Can someone please tell me what I need to do?

For extra information; I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 currently. Not very familiar with the system as I used to have Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just kill the `gnome-software` process by running the following command in the terminal:

```
killall gnome-software
```

Alternatively, you can end the process using a more Windows-like way by launching System Monitor → *Processes* tab → <kbd>right click</kbd> on *Gnome Software* → *Kill*.

Comment: So, after doing this would it then be safe to restart my system? I know it's a bit of a stupid question for me to ask, but I'm just really anxious about basically breaking my entire computer over this.

Edit: I've already killed it using the terminal.

Comment: Sure, I don't think there would be a problem, since the application is installed correctly. It's just the Gnome Software that froze. Either way, what else could you do? Never restart again? :)

Comment: Well, it’s not even that the software center froze or crashed. I could still open and use it as normal if not for the fact that it was stuck “installing” that program. Anyways, thanks for your help. This was giving me pretty bad anxiety.

Comment: Well... I think I might have a new issue on my hands. Was trying to restart my system and I got this pop up saying that “Authentication is required for rebooting the system while an application asked to inhibit it.” Could the software I’m still trying to install still really BE installing or something?

Comment: That's weird. I've never seen that error before. I would just restart anyway, but maybe you would want to ask a new question about this error here.

Comment: Alright, well... thanks for the help so far. I’m not going to risk it until I know I won’t have to have someone take it to a repair shop for me. I’m going on vacation in a few days and I won’t really have the time to get this repaired until it’s over.