# New restart error? “Authentication is required for rebooting the system while an application is asked to inhibit it.”

Tags: system, administration

Okay, so this is a follow up question to my last one, about my “issue” installing VirtualBox off the Software Center. I did what I was asked to with the Software Center, as it looks like VirtualBox installed without a problem despite what Software Center was saying. However every time I try to restart now (I still haven’t yet), I get the error listed above. Can someone explain to me what it means and is it safe to restart now?

Sorry for the poor formatting, I temp switched to mobile while I try to figure out what I should do.

Edit: Apologies. Forgot to post a link. Here; [Installating software off Ubuntu Store "frozen". How do I safely stop this/restart my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148991/installating-software-off-ubuntu-store-frozen-how-do-i-safely-stop-this-resta/1148995?noredirect=1#comment1909340_1148995)

Comment: Please post a link to your previous question.AskUbuntu is a very busy site and questions quickly move out of the current view. I often have trouble with the Ubuntu repository version of VirtualBox and have better luck with the version released by VirtualBox. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.

Comment: Well, I just edited my last question in. I wasn’t sure what category to initially even put this in, but now that I’m getting some feedback I’m assuming I have it in the right place now. Anyways, it’s not an issue I’m having with VirtualBox, but rather with restarting my system.

Comment: Right. It looks like VB is stuck in its setup. It sets up some virtual network devices and it could have run into an issue there. But whatever the problem, it's clear that it's stuck and you're going to have to kill that process somehow. I would kill any processes involved in that installation -- apt and virtualbox -- and then . `apt purge virtualbox` to clear all its artifacts, and then install from the VB site.

Comment: Well, is there any process I need to be looking for specifically before I can run that command? I’ve already killed the process for the Software Center and it doesn’t appear VirtualBox is running in my processes.

Comment: Ah good. And the restart is still locked so it is probably just a stale lock. I understand your caution, I do -- there are so many moving parts -- but if this were my problem I'd go ahead with the reboot. That will break the lock. Are you trying to reboot through the GUI? Or are you at a terminal. I'd use the terminal and sudo the reboot. Purge. Re-install VB from VB site. If you are already at the terminal and using sudo then **I** would just swear and pull the plug. But that's  just me. I've been using Linux since 1994 but I'm still no expert. Though I've broken a system only once so...